# How to limit number of rows in osmnx

Tags: python, openstreetmap, osmnx

Is there a way to limit the function

```
ox.geometries_from_place()
```

in order to return a limited number of rows?

If a large place is inserted (like Rome), the function become too slow

Comment: Limit by what? You should specify the `tags`(and possibly `buffer_dist`) so that you only get the objects you are interested in.

Comment: sorry @MSpiller I want to limit the number of rows that the function returns, since it's really slow

Comment: You should provide a complete minimal reproducible example so we can see exactly what and how you're querying.

Comment: Again, limit the number of rows by what? The most effective way is to simply not query all objects but limit them to certain tags. If you ask for _just give me the first 10 results, no matter what they are_ that will not work using that API.